# Using IMPORTXML with IF and contains?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am new to google sheets and I have been working with the IMPORTXML function for a few now.
However, I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is possible with this function.

Basically, I am trying to scrape data from a webpage using IMPORTXML Like So:
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/","//tr")`

Now if that extracted tr contains an IMG child element, I want to scrape it using:
`=IMAGE(IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/","//tr/td//img//@src"))`

Otherwise, I want it to leave a blank cell or fill it with text such as "Blank"

I've been starting with something like this but I think I am way off.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/","//tr/td//img//@src")), "Blank", IMAGE(IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/","//tr//td//img//@src"))))`

The problem is I am able to just extract every cell that contains an image, but when it doesn't contain an image, it just skips over and fills the next cell.  I want to make sure that excel can check this and leave an empty cell when tr does not contain an img.

Comment: whats the url??

Comment: Does it absolutely matter?  The html is implied that is has children "tr/td//img//@src"

If you feel that it is necessary I will give it but I am trying to maintain anonymity with my project @player0

Comment: Add a sample data returned by the IMPORTXML functions. Actually you could simplify your question by keeping out the IMPORTXML part ans focusing it on how Google Sheets handle arrays the the use of IF function.

Comment: Does this answer your question [XPath simple conditional statement? If node X exists, do Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13576379/1595451)?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, but that doesn't answer how to skip and leave an empty cell/return "Blank" if the node doesn't exist